# How to give static message in google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using google map API, it is working fine, like in this map if I click a marker, one dialogue box opens displaying the location address; instead of this I want to display a static value. How can I change my code to do this?

```js
function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: 12.9577129, lng: 77.6764937} // Starting Point Marathahalli
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
       
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
        
        /* configure waypoints */
        var waypts = [];
        waypts.push(
   {
              location: {lat: 12.9583665, lng: 77.6635659}, // HAL
              stopover: true
            } ,{
              location: {lat: 12.9630167, lng: 77.6268656},
              stopover: true
            }
   );
            
        directionsService.route({
          origin: {lat: 12.9577129, lng: 77.6764937},  // Haight.
          destination: {lat: 12.9868068, lng: 77.6070679},  // Ending Point Shivaji Nagar.
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
          waypoints: waypts
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   console.log(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="testForm">
 <select name="tripId">
  <option value=""></option>
 </select>
  </form>
  
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to display?  What do you mean by a "static message"? Where? On which marker(s) (there are 4 in that posted code)?

Comment: In this Map, click on marker ,after that one dialogue box it will open , in this  dialogue  box address in displaying now, for me instead of address i want to display My Company name

Comment: That would only be one of the markers then (I assume the last one), not all of them.  To change the InfoWindows you have to suppress the markers and add your own with the associated infowindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the InfoWindows you have to suppress the markers and add your own with the associated infowindow.

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressMarkers: true
});
```

custom renderer for the markers:

```
var startLocation, endLocation, waypts;
function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    waypts = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var route = response.routes[0];
    startLocation = new Object();
    endLocation = new Object();

    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
        startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
        startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)));
      } else {
        waypts[i] = new Object();
        waypts[i].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
        waypts[i].address = legs[i].start_address;
        waypts[i].marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "waypoint" + i, legs[i].start_address, "yellow", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i));
      }
      endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
      endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
      var steps = legs[i].steps;
      for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
          bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
        }
      }
    }

    endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "My Company", endLocation.address, "red", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + waypts.length));
    google.maps.event.trigger(endLocation.marker, 'click');
  } else alert(status);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5ex1d44x/3/) (based off of this example: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsE.html)

[image: screen shot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var gmarkers = [];

function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 12.9577129,
      lng: 77.6764937
    } // Starting Point Marathahalli
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
  /* configure waypoints */
  var waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
    location: {
      lat: 12.9583665,
      lng: 77.6635659
    }, // HAL
    stopover: true
  }, {
    location: {
      lat: 12.9630167,
      lng: 77.6268656
    },
    stopover: true
  });

  directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      lat: 12.9577129,
      lng: 77.6764937
    }, // Haight.
    destination: {
      lat: 12.9868068,
      lng: 77.6070679
    }, // Ending Point Shivaji Nagar.
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
    waypoints: waypts
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      RenderCustomDirections(response, status);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    waypts = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var route = response.routes[0];
    startLocation = new Object();
    endLocation = new Object();

    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
        startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
        startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)));
      } else {
        waypts[i] = new Object();
        waypts[i].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
        waypts[i].address = legs[i].start_address;
        waypts[i].marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "waypoint" + i, legs[i].start_address, "yellow", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i));
      }
      endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
      endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
      var steps = legs[i].steps;
      for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
          bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
        }
      }
    }
    endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "My Company", endLocation.address, "red", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + waypts.length));
    google.maps.event.trigger(endLocation.marker, 'click');
  } else alert(status);
}

var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = {
  url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
  // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
  size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
  labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
};

function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
  if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
    iconColor = "red";
  }
  if (!icons[iconColor]) {
    icons[iconColor] = {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + iconColor + ".png",
      // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
    };
  }
  return icons[iconColor];

}
// Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
// where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
// in the top left of the image.

// Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
// increase in the X direction to the right and in
// the Y direction down.

var iconImage = {
  url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34)
};
// Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var iconShape = {
  coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
  type: 'poly'
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, title, html, color, label) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + title + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    icon: getMarkerImage(color),
    shape: iconShape,
    title: title,
    label: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = title;
  gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  return marker;
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<title>Travel modes in directions</title>
<form id="testForm">
  <select name="tripId">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
  <select id="mode">
    <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Mr@geocodezip, I copied your code but it is not working, like marker is not showing

Comment: My example(s) work, you must not have copied all the code (or made any required adjustments for your site). Any JavaScript errors?  You will need to fix them.  If you need help on your version, please post a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (that is probably another question though)

Comment: Okay i got the answer,Thanks