# Adding info window to direction map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the code from https://www.sitepoint.com/find-a-route-using-the-geolocation-and-the-google-maps-api/ to build a journey planner from the user's location to an option of several football stadiums.

I have managed to do that with the code below, but I would like to add another element. I would like to add info windows to the destination markers (opens on click) with the stadium name and description.

I have tried adding the code from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

...but it does not work.

Could someone help?

Here is my code :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Find a route using Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
  function calculateRoute(from, to) {
    // Center initialized somewhere near London
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // Draw the map
    var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRequest = {
      origin: from,
      destination: to,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    directionsService.route(
      directionsRequest,
      function(response, status)
      {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
          new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: mapObject,
            directions: response
          });
        }
        else
          $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
      }
    );
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
      $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
      return;
    }

    $("#from-link, #to-link").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
          "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
        },
        function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            $("#" + addressId).val(results[0].formatted_address);
          else
            $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
        });
      },


      function(positionError){
        $("#error").append("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />");
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
      });
    });

    $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      calculateRoute($("#from").val(), $("#to").val());
    });


  });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Calculate your route</h1>
<form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
  <label for="from">From:</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" />
  <a id="from-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
  <br />

  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <select id="to">
    <option value="51.5548885,-0.108438">Arsenal's Emirates Stadium</option>
    <option value="51.481663,-0.1931505">Chelsea's Stamford Bridge</option>
  </select>

  <br />

  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="reset" />
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<p id="error"></p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the infoWindow when using google directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597630/changing-the-infowindow-when-using-google-directions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3 - waypoints + infowindow with random text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083639/google-maps-v3-waypoints-infowindow-with-random-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give static message in google map API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611594/how-to-give-static-message-in-google-map-api)

Comment: please, read this post: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you, I will study these as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `suppressMarkers:true` on the `DirectionsRenderer` to remove the original markers.

```
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  map: mapObject,
  directions: response,
  suppressMarkers: true
});
```

2. add a `createMarker` function to create new markers (from similar question: [How to give static message in google map API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611594/how-to-give-static-message-in-google-map-api):

```
function createMarker(latlng, title, html, color, label, map) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + title + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    icon: getMarkerImage(color),
    shape: iconShape,
    title: title,
    label: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = title;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  return marker;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gLjuqbep/1/)

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function calculateRoute(from, to) {
  // Center initialized somewhere near London
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  // Draw the map
  var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRequest = {
    origin: from,
    destination: to,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
  };
  directionsService.route(
    directionsRequest,
    function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          map: mapObject,
          directions: response,
          suppressMarkers: true
        });
        console.log(response.routes.length);
        createMarker(response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location, "start", document.getElementById('from').value, "green", "A", mapObject);
        createMarker(response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location, "end", $("#to option:selected").text(), "red", "B", mapObject)
      } else
        $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
    }
  );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
  if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
    $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
    return;
  }

  $("#from-link, #to-link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
          },
          function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
              $("#" + addressId).val(results[0].formatted_address);
            else
              $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
          });
      },


      function(positionError) {
        $("#error").append("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />");
      }, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
      });
  });

  $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculateRoute($("#from").val(), $("#to").val());
  });
});
var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = {
  url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
  // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
  size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
  labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
};

function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
  if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
    iconColor = "red";
  }
  if (!icons[iconColor]) {
    icons[iconColor] = {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + iconColor + ".png",
      // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
    };
  }
  return icons[iconColor];

}
// Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
// where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
// in the top left of the image.

// Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
// increase in the X direction to the right and in
// the Y direction down.

var iconImage = {
  url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34)
};
// Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var iconShape = {
  coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
  type: 'poly'
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, title, html, color, label, map) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + title + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    icon: getMarkerImage(color),
    shape: iconShape,
    title: title,
    label: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = title;
  // gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  return marker;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<h1>Calculate your route</h1>
<form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
  <label for="from">From:</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" value="Croydon, UK" />
  <a id="from-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
  <br />

  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <select id="to">
    <option value="51.5548885,-0.108438">Arsenal's Emirates Stadium</option>
    <option value="51.481663,-0.1931505">Chelsea's Stamford Bridge</option>
  </select>

  <br />

  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="reset" />
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<p id="error"></p>
```